# Como ejecutar Selenium Javascript al presionar un boton en una pagina HTML

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

Hace unas semanas estoy programando en Javascript e implementando Selenium, el archivo .js lo tengo "cargado" en un html, la mayoría de las funciones trabajan bien, el problema que tengo es cuando quiero ejecutar la función que utiliza Selenium, El código que tengo es el siguiente:

Esta función la agregue porque pensé que simplemente al ejecutar el botón no respondía con la otra función.

```
function run(){
    try {
        alert("Entro aca");
        test();
    } catch (error) {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
```

Y esta es la que contiene código de Selenium:

```
async function test() {
    alert("ENTRO A TEST");
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
    alert("ENTRO A TEST 2");
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}
```

Y esta ultima es donde tengo el boton con la llamada de la funcion:

```
<button class="button" id="btn" onclick="run()">Button</button>
```

Dejé esos alert entre medio para saber donde tenía el problema, y descubrí que simplemente la línea donde uso Builder no se ejecuta, o desconozco si se ejecuta escondida, porque el **alert("ENTRO A TEST")** si se muestra en la pagina pero el **alert("ENTRO A TEST 2")** no lo hace.

Comment: y si quitas el primer alert, no se muestra el segundo? se supone que hasta que le dices a selenium que cierre el alert se queda esperando

Comment: Exacto, podría dejar solo el segundo pero aún así no se muestra.

Comment: Y si ejecutas test() desde la consola tampoco? Probaste cambiar los alerts por statements `console.log`?

Comment: desde consola y con terminal de visual studio code, que es donde trabajo, en ambos se ejecuta todo perfecto.

Comment: Entonces no llega al segundo porque no le has dicho a Selenium que cierre el Alert

Comment: borré todos los alert y solo dejé el que esta despues de let driver y sigue sin aparecer... :( ya no se que mas intentar

Comment: saca ese alert pues. O dile a Selenium que lo cierre con  `driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();`.